# How to cite a particular Theorem while referring a paper

Tags: citing

I want to cite a particular theorem of a paper in the following way:

> In [5, Theorem 2.2], ........

While using the command `\cite{...}`, I can only refer the paper number from the bibliography. Is it possible to refer in the desired way? Kindly help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\cite[Theorem~5.5]{sigfridsson}`

Comment: Is there any news here? Was the comment helpful?